# Traceback length of re-raised exceptions are increasing when using asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have this case where coroutines have dependency on an other coroutine. If an exception occurs in the given dependency all the dependents should stop and log the traceback. However as the exception is re-raised the traceback is getting longer and longer.

```python
# coding: utf-8

import asyncio
import traceback

async def resource():
    return 7 / 0

async def worker(dependency):
    print('waiting on a dependency')

    try:
        await dependency
    except Exception as e:
        print('Worker crashed:\n' + traceback.format_exc())


async def main(loop):
    dependency = loop.create_task(resource())

    workers = [loop.create_task(worker(dependency)) for _ in range(4)]

    return await asyncio.wait(workers, loop=loop)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))

    loop.stop()
    loop.close()
```

For the first run the traceback is like this:

```
waiting on a dependency
Worker crashed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/slapec/scripts/sandbox/exc.py", line 13, in worker
    await dependency
  File "/home/slapec/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 360, in __iter__
    return self.result()  # May raise too.
  File "/home/slapec/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/slapec/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/home/slapec/scripts/sandbox/exc.py", line 7, in resource
    return 7 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

After the 4th iteration, it is like this:

```
    waiting on a dependency
Worker crashed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/slapec/scripts/sandbox/exc.py", line 13, in worker
    await dependency
  File "/home/slapec/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 360, in __iter__
    return self.result()  # May raise too.
  File "/home/slapec/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/slapec/scripts/sandbox/exc.py", line 13, in worker
    await dependency
  File "/home/slapec/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 360, in __iter__
    return self.result()  # May raise too.
  File "/home/slapec/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/slapec/scripts/sandbox/exc.py", line 13, in worker
    await dependency
  File "/home/slapec/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 360, in __iter__
    return self.result()  # May raise too.
  File "/home/slapec/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/slapec/scripts/sandbox/exc.py", line 13, in worker
    await dependency
  File "/home/slapec/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 360, in __iter__
    return self.result()  # May raise too.
  File "/home/slapec/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/slapec/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/home/slapec/scripts/sandbox/exc.py", line 7, in resource
    return 7 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

AFAIK it's not really asyncio-specific but I've never seen this behaviour before.

Do you know how if it's possible to keep the original traceback? I have a feeling that stack frames are also stored so a long-running loop would eat all my memory.

Comment: In python3.6 the traceback is somewhat shorter, but can still include all `await`s awaiting the same dependency.